# Check if node T can be reached from node S in a DG

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

In an undirected graph, it is easily possible to pre-partition the graph into components and tag them with numbers identifying the components. So to check whether a node T can be reached via a path from S is true iff they both have the same tag.

Is it possible to do something similar in a directed graph? Basically, to precompute and then do a simple lookup whether T can be reached from S without any kind of DFS?

Comment: The tricky case is going to be when your graph is a directed acyclic graph, where this essentially becomes “precompute something that solves the directed reachability problem efficiently.” I’m not sure how to do that without a DFS, but I suspect that’s possible with some creativity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the most naive implementation of reachability matrices and their optimizations (which is of the complexity of O(n^2). I'm afraid there is no constant time lookup.

There are a few interesting ideas though. I'll list two of them below:

1) Finding a set of Trees covering the original graph G. Such that [image: 1]

Each vertex V is indexed as follow:

```
For each t_i in T

    V is indexed by (t_i, a, b) where a is the smallest postorder of descendants in the tree and b is the postorder of V in the tree.
```

In order to query reach(u, v), we are to find whether there exist a pair of *(t_i, a_u, b_u)* and *(t_i, a_v, b_v)* such that *u_a <= v_b < u_b*. For details, please see

> R. Agrawal, A. Borgida, and H. V. Jagadish. Efficient management of
>   transitive relationships in large data and knowledge bases. In
>   Proceedings of the 1989 ACM SIGMOD international conference on
>   Management of data (SIGMOD 1989), 1989.

Then the problems are reduced to how to find a minimal set of Trees T that covers the how graph G. There are various method of doing so.

2) Another school of approach is the n-hop (see the SODA 02 publication)

> Reachability and distance queries via 2-hop labels by Edith Cohen,Eran Halperin,Haim Kaplan,Uri Zwick

```
Let G = (V, E) be a directed graph. 
For v in V
    L(v) = (L_in(v), L_out(v)), such that L_in(v), L_out(v) ⊆ V and there is a path from every x ∈ L_in(v) to v and from v to every x ∈ L_out(v).
```

The problem is then reduced to finding an optimal 2-hop cover

> Let G = (V, E) be a graph. For every u, v ∈ V , let P_uv be a
>   collection of paths from u to v (for undirected graphs we have P_uv ≡
>   P_vu). Let P = {P_uv}. We define a hop to be a pair (h, u), where h is a
>   path in G and u ∈ V is one of the endpoints of h. We refer to u as the
>   handle of the hop. A collection of hops H is said to be a 2-hop cover
>   of P if for every u, v ∈ V such that Puv 6= φ, there is a path p ∈
>   Puv, and two hops (h1, u) ∈ H and (h2, v) ∈ H, such that p = h1h2,
>   i.e., p is the concatenation of h1 and h2. The size of the cover is
>   |H|, the number of hops in H.